# Integral $\int-\sin x\mathrm e^{-\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate the function $$-\sin x\mathrm{e}^{-\sin x}.$$
I tried integration by parts with $u=-\sin x$ but I got another difficult integration which is $$\int (\cos x)^{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\sin x} \,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Could someone help me out?

Comment: If you do the variable substitution $u = - \sin x$, you should get a different integral from what you write -- something more like $- \int (u/\sqrt{1-u^2})\, e^u du$.

Comment: @Stijn Isn't the integral just $ue^u$? The original integral is $-\sin x e^{-
 \sin x}$, and the second integral is just what the OP tried.

Comment: @TobyMak This integral is not $\int ue^u\;du$. $du  = -\cos(x) dx \neq dx$.

Comment: It is cos^2(x)  in the second one and not just cos (x)  but don't know how to edit that

Comment: Just to add, to do integration by parts (with "$u$" and "$v$" in whatever implicit conventions you have), since you would need  $du/dx$ to be something like $-\sin x$, $u$ would have to be $\cos x$, not $-\sin x$. I do not think this will really help either way.

Comment: Where does this integral come from, anyways?

Comment: Could the problem be for a definite integral ? For $\int_0^{\pi/2}$, the result is interesting.

Comment: @cws it comes from when I tried to evaluate a line integral of vector field with a little bit difficult function

Comment: @Claude Leibovici,yes it is definit from 0 to 2π

Comment: @FarhanOmar: please say this in your question!! People can waste a lot of time trying to find an indefinite integral when the definite integral is much easier (and indeed possible).

Comment: How it wil become easier if it is definite ?we do need to antiderivate it to get the definition integral and I was wondering if it's possible or not.

Comment: We dont always need an antiderivative to find the definite integral. For example one could do a contour integration using the residue theorem

Comment: By the way, giving WA **integrate -sin(x) exp(-sin(x)) from 0 to 2 pi** provides the result.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that you could find the antiderivative.

Set $\sin(x)=t$ to make the integrand $-t\, e^{-t}$ and then
$$-t e^{-t}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}$$ making
$$\int-\sin (x)\,\mathrm e^{-\sin (x)}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\int \sin^{n+1}(x)\,dx$$

**Edit**

Since, in comments, the problem is said for the integral between $0$ and $2\pi$, let us use
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{n+1}(x)\,dx=-\sqrt{\pi }\frac{ \left((-1)^n-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}$$ which are equal to $0$ if $n$ is even.

This makes by the end$$-\int_0^{2\pi}\sin (x)\,\mathrm e^{-\sin (x)}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{  2^{-2 n}\, \pi}{\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (n+2)} =2 \pi  I_1(1)$$ where appears the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Looking for explicit results, using the same approach as above for $\int_0^{\frac{n\pi}2} \sin^{n+1}(x)\,dx$, I only found some for
$$I_n=-\int_0^{\frac{n\pi}2} \sin(x)\,\mathrm e^{-\sin (x)}\,dx$$ the key ones being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & I_n \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} \pi  (I_1(1)-\pmb{L}_{-1}(1)) \\
 2 & \pi  (I_1(1)-\pmb{L}_{-1}(1)) \\
 3 & \frac{1}{2} \pi  (3 I_1(1)-\pmb{L}_{-1}(1)) \\
 4 & 2 \pi  I_1(1)
\end{array}
\right)$$ where also appears the modified Struve function.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, thanks for the answer actually in the origin problem it was possible  to  go from line integral to double integral by Green therom or to triple integral by Gauss theorem  which was easy but I wanted to evaluate the line integral and check if it was possible and will give the same answer but unfortunately I got that integral in my way.

Comment: @klirk. I am not computing the integral. Just representing the integrand as an infinite sum of powers of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I got it now...thats why I deleted my comments. You only use the series expansion of the exponential function. That was not clear (at least to me) from your answer.

Comment: @klirk. This is correct. Sorry for not being clear ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\cos x\,e^{\sin x}dx$$ is elementary. Using the chain rule, it is easy to see that the antiderivative is $$e^{\sin x}.$$

On the opposite,

$$\int\sin x\,e^{\sin x}dx$$ has no closed-form expression.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
-\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)\,e^{-\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)\,e^{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(x)\,\sinh(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^{2k+2}(x)}{(2k+1)!}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{4^{k+1}}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}\frac1{(2k+1)!}\\
&=\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{4^kk!(k+1)!}\\[6pt]
&=2\pi\operatorname{I}_1(1)\\[15pt]
&=3.5509993784243618938
\end{align}
$$
$\operatorname{I}_1$ is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). In any case, the sum converges quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

$-\int\mathrm e^{-\sin x}\sin x~dx=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+2}x}{(2n+1)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n)!}dx$

For $n$ is any non-negative integer,

$\int\sin^{2n+2}x~dx=\dfrac{(2n+2)!x}{4^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(2n+2)!(k!)^2\sin^{2k+1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}((n+1)!)^2(2k+1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

$\int\sin^{2n+1}x~dx$

$=-\int\sin^{2n}x~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int(1-\cos^2x)^n~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^nC_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}x~d(\cos x)$

$=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$\therefore\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+2}x}{(2n+1)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n)!}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n+2)!x}{4^{n+1}(2n+1)!((n+1)!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(2n+2)!(k!)^2\sin^{2k+1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}(2n+1)!((n+1)!)^2(2k+1)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2(n+1)x}{4^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{2(n+1)(k!)^2\sin^{2k+1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}((n+1)!)^2(2k+1)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{2^{2n+1}n!(n+1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(k!)^2\sin^{2k+1}x\cos x}{2^{2n-2k+1}n!(n+1)!(2k+1)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}x}{(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$